# cl.exe gives an error when trying to compile a C++ source file. How can I fix this?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, compiler-errors, compilation, visual-studio-2017

So I am trying to compile a C++ source file on Windows 10 using the Visual C++ command line compiler. When I try to compile my source code, I would get this error.

```
> cl /EHsc days.cpp

Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.10.25019 for x64
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

days.cpp
days.cpp(1): fatal error C1034: iostream: no include path set
```

I researched online to see if I can find a solution, however the recommendations that were suggested didn't work for me.

I did use 'vcvarsall.bat' prior to using 'cl' but it still didn't worked and the similar questions that I encountered were pertaining to earlier versions of Visual Studio IDE (I am using Visual Studio IDE 2017).

Also, here is the source code that I am trying to run. I do believe it is error free.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
enum Days{Sunday,Monday,Tuesday,Wednesday,Thursday,Friday,Saturday};

Days TheDay;
int j;
cout<<"Please enter the day of the week (0 to 6)";
cin>>j;
TheDay = Days(j);

if(TheDay == Sunday || TheDay == Saturday)
cout<<"Hurray it is the weekend"<<endl;
else
cout<<"Curses still at work"<<endl;

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Maybe the SDK is missing? Start the installer and (re)install C++.

Comment: ***I did use 'vcvarsall.bat' prior to using 'cl' but it still didn't worked and the similar questions that I*** An additional option is to run the build from the correct Visual Studio command prompt for 32 or 64 bit. However I also suspect that your don't have the native `c++` compiler fully installed.

Comment: I thought I installed the native C++ compiler when I installed Visual Studio Build Tools. How do I install the native c++ compiler?

Comment: It will be a choice in the install for Visual Studio.

Comment: What is the specific checkbox do I have to click on? What is the specific name may I ask?

Comment: I don't remember. I last installed Visual Studio 2017 weeks ago.

Comment: ***no include path set*** This seems suspicious. You should have an `INCLUDE` environment variable. Type `SET` in your build command prompt to see the variables.

Comment: Choose "Desktop development with C++"

Comment: manni66, I did that.

Comment: I do have an include variable when I type `SET`, drescherjm.

Comment: Anyone have solution for this?